# How can I only pull in data for radio group filtering one time instead of for each entry in the database?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm creating a radio group selector for filtering returning data, but I'm stuck on a final area.

It's pulling in all of the proper "Area of Focus", however it does it for each item in the database. What I'm trying to do is get it to just show once per "Area of Focus" instead of for every entry. You can see what it's doing in the image below.

[image]

I believe the issue sits somewhere in the code below, but I'm not sure what it is. I added the script for more context.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
     <v-radio-group class="ml-2" v-model="filters.areaOfFocus" column>
        <v-radio
          v-for="areaOfFocus in areaOfFocuses"
          :key="areaOfFocus"
          :label="areaOfFocus"
          :value="areaOfFocus"
          color="#C5D5EA"
        ></v-radio>
      </v-radio-group>
```

**Script**

```
export default {
  name: "CapacityBuilding",
  props: ["tools"],
  data() {
    return {
      menu1: false,
      menu2: false,
      menu3: false,
      FullProfileDialog: false,
      error: null,
      filters: {
        keyword: null,
        areaOfFocus: null,
        resourceType: null,
        resourceFormat: null,
      },
      viewingEntity: null,
      areaofFocuses: [],
      resourceTypes: [],
      resourceFormats: [],
      filteredTools: [],
      websiteLink: [],
      videoLink: [],
      file: [],
      toolHeaders: [
        { text: "Name", value: "attributes.name", width: "30%" },
        {
          text: "Category",
          value: "attributes.contentResourceTopic",
          width: "20%",
        },
        {
          text: "Format",
          value: "attributes.contentResourceFormat",
          width: "15%",
        },
        { text: "Type", value: "attributes.contentResourceType", width: "20%" },
        {
          text: "Actions",
          value: "actions",
          align: "center",
          sortable: false,
          width: "20%",
          class: "actions-text",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.areaOfFocuses = this.tools
      .map((t) => t.attributes.contentAreaOfFocus)
      .sort();
    this.resourceTypes = this.tools
      .map((t) => t.attributes.contentResourceType)
      .sort();
    this.resourceFormats = this.tools
      .map((t) => t.attributes.contentResourceFormat)
      .sort();
    this.filteredTools = this.tools;
  },
  methods: {
    async applyFilters() {
      var tempFilteredTools = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tools));

      if (this.filters.keyword) {
        var searchBy = this.filters.keyword.toLowerCase();

        tempFilteredTools = tempFilteredTools.filter(
          (q) =>
            q.attributes.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBy) !== -1 ||
            (q.attributes.contentResourceFormat &&
              q.attributes.contentResourceFormat
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(searchBy) !== -1) ||
            (q.attributes.contentResourceTopic &&
              q.attributes.contentResourceTopic
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(searchBy) !== -1) ||
            (q.attributes.contentResourceType &&
              q.attributes.contentResourceType
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(searchBy) !== -1)
        );
      }

      if (this.filters.areaOfFocus) {
        tempFilteredTools = tempFilteredTools.filter(
          (q) => q.attributes.contentAreaOfFocus === this.filters.areaOfFocus
        );
      }

      if (this.filters.resourceType) {
        tempFilteredTools = tempFilteredTools.filter(
          (q) => q.attributes.contentResourceType === this.filters.resourceType
        );
      }

      if (this.filters.resourceFormat) {
        tempFilteredTools = tempFilteredTools.filter(
          (q) =>
            q.attributes.contentResourceFormat === this.filters.resourceFormat
        );
      }

      this.filteredTools = tempFilteredTools;
    },
    async resetSearch() {
      this.filters = {
        areaOfFocus: null,
        resourceFormat: null,
        resourceType: null,
        keyword: null,
      };
      await this.applyFilters();
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicates:

```js
const tools = [{attributes: {contentAreaOfFocus: 'c'}}, {attributes: {contentAreaOfFocus: 'b'}}, {attributes: {contentAreaOfFocus: 'c'}}, {attributes: {contentAreaOfFocus: 'a'}}, {attributes: {contentAreaOfFocus: 'a'}}]
const areaOfFocuses = [... new Set(tools.map(a => a.attributes.contentAreaOfFocus).sort())]
console.log(areaOfFocuses)
```